# average using bit shift and array in ADC interrupt

Tags: c, average, interrupt, microcontroller, mplab

I have an ADC interrupt that I'd like to sample the channel (ADCBUF0) 8 times, then take the average of the samples. My code utilizes flags to jump out of the if statement. The code compiles and my variables are initialized elsewhere. Could someone please tell me why I am not receiving a value for SpeedADC???

```
///////Global////////////
int SpeedADCcount=0;
/////////////////////////

SpeedADCflag=1;
    if(SpeedADCflag==1)     //The following is meant to take a an average of the incoming ADC voltages
    {
        SpeedADCcount++;
        for(i = SpeedADCcount; i < 16; i++)
        {
            while(!ADCON1bits.SAMP);    //Sample Done?          
            ADCON1bits.SAMP=0;          //Start Converting
            while(!ADCON1bits.DONE);    //Conversion Done? Should be on next Tcy cycle
            SpeedADCarray[i] = ADCBUF0;
            SpeedADCflag=0;
        }
    }
    if(SpeedADCcount==15)
    {

        SpeedADC=SpeedADCarray[i]>>4;
        SpeedADCcount=0;
        // Re-enable the motor if it was turned off previous
        if((SpeedADC>246) && Flags.RunMotor==0){RunMotor();}

        /*Go through another stage of "filtering" for any analog input voltage below 1.25volts
```

Comment: Where are you calculating the average?

Comment: I was assuming that the average would be defined as SpeedADC=SpeedADCarray[i]>>SpeedADCcount

Comment: That's dividing *one* of your samples by 2^SpeedADCcount (where ^ is "to the power of").

Comment: If you want to divide, divide, don't shift. The compiler should optimize to a shift anyway if the divisor is a power of 2.

Comment: I've since changed it, but how would I get it so that I will sample and place into the array everytime I go through the interrupt up to 16 times, then bit-shift the entire array to get the average after I sampled 16 times with 16 values in the array?

Comment: Sum the array into a single variable, then divide it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the right downshift amount (to avoid dividing), such that 8 -> 3, 16 -> 4, etc.  For 8 samples, you only need to downshift 3 (3 bits).

And you need to sum all of the values in a single value, not put them in separate array entries.

```
SpeedADCarray += ADCBUF0;  /* accumulate in a single integer, not an array */
```